# Redux/toolkit TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am using redux/toolkit and entity adapter in my app. The problem is that when I want to add selectors to my slice I got undefined for store.getState();

I write this based on [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#selector-functions) documentation.

driverReducer.ts

```
const driversAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Driver>({
  sortComparer: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name),
});

export const DriverSlice = createSlice({
  name: "drivers",
  initialState: driversAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    setDrivers: driversAdapter.setAll,
    driverAdded: driversAdapter.addOne,
    driverUpdated: driversAdapter.updateOne,
    driverRemoved: driversAdapter.removeOne,
  },
});

const driversSelectors = driversAdapter.getSelectors<RootState>(state => state.drivers);
export const selectAllDrivers = driversSelectors.selectAll(store.getState());


export default DriverSlice.reducer;
```

store.ts

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    drivers:driverReduces,
  },
});
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error message?

Comment: I got this error when adding `store.getState()` to the `driversSelectors.selectAll` . 
@phry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency here.

Your `store.ts` needs to import `DriverSlice` from `driverReducer.ts`.
Your `driverReducer.ts`needs to import `store` from `store.ts`.

A file can only be evaluated fully, so with both files having to be evaluated before the other, that's just not possible.

Solution?
Move your
`export const selectAllDrivers = driversSelectors.selectAll(store.getState());`
to another file.

Also note, that `selectAllDrivers` will be the result of evaluating `driversSelectors.selectAll(store.getState())` once at the beginning - so it will likely just be your initial state. That is probably not what you want, but not really the subject of this question.

Comment: Thanks, @phry. Moving those selectors to another file disappeared the error. However, I cannot get the drivers from my component by calling `selectAllDrivers `. It returned an empty array as a list of drivers.

Comment: Because you do not use selectors like that, at all. Where are you planning to use those? In a React component?

Comment: Yes, in a react component. 
I can use `driversSelectors.selectAll(store.getState())` in my component and it works. But, this is not the best way for getting state. What do you suggest?

Comment: Never call `store.getState()` in your component. You need to use `react-redux` for that. Otherwise store changes will not udpate the component with relevant data.
`const myData = useSelector(driversSelector.selectAll)`